# Entity Framework Code First mapping a Navigation Property as a Column in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Code First Migration. The Customer `Role` Property is a navigation property but the entity framework maps this property as a Column in the Database! What's wrong in my code as follows:

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public byte RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RoleId` data type in `Customer` class is mismatched! Make it `int` instead of `byte`  as follows:

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Okay! Thank you too! marked it as answer by clicking the check sign on the left!

Comment: @TanvirArjel That's why we're all here! 

Comment: @JohnyL yeh! but this brother is may be new to `stack overflow` and that's why I have guided him :)

Comment: @TanvirArjel I'm just kiddin' :) Yes, I do agree with you that some people just forget to push that button. 